# Right tenses usage

Tags: tense

Could someone kindly explain the difference between these sentences:

I never expected to be as happy as I was on that day.

I have never expected to be as happy as I was on that day.

I would never expect to be as happy as I was on that day.

I would have never expected to be as happy as I was on that day.

And could I also use all these sentences with today instead of on that day? So it would be:

I never expected to be as happy as I am today.

I have never expected to be as happy as I am today.

I would never expect to be as happy as I am today.

I would have never expected to be as happy as I am today.

I will be grateful for an explicit and comprehensive explanation what exactly is the difference.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all cases, what's "unexpected" is that *I was/am happy [on that day/today]*. So lets's call that ***X***...

> 1) *I never expected X [to happen, or to be true]*
>    2) *I have never expected X*
>    3) *I would never expect X*
>    4) *I would have never expected X*

Idiomatically, #1 above is the normal way of expressing the fact that at no time in the past did the speaker expect X to happen. Note - this form is usually used in contexts where there's a strong implication that ***X has in fact now happened*** (*X is "true",* contrary to the speaker's expectations).

The Present Perfect version #2 doesn't normally carry any implication that X is true. In fact, it's more likely to be used in contexts where X *didn't* happen (sometimes, where it's just been proven that X *could never happen*, and the speaker is "boasting" that he always "knew" it wouldn't happen).

Present Perfect implies a strong connection between past and present states (so *I have lived here for years* implies *I still live here now*). This creates semantic problems when the unexpected even is *itself* in the past. Consider, for example, *?I have never expected Trump to win last year*. It's hard to see how the speaker could *still* not be expecting Trump to win, and he certainly can't be boasting about having been proved correct.

---

Including the modal ***would*** in versions #3 and #4 is often just a stylistic device that makes little if any difference to the meaning. Being pedantic, it implies that in the past I never even considered the possibility of X occurring - but if I *had* thought about it, I *would* have decided I didn't expect it.

Interestingly, whereas #1 / #2 are primarily distinguished by the fact that the Simple Past form (#1) usually implies *X **is** true*, and Present Perfect implies it's ***not***, these implications can be effectively "reversed" when modal ***would*** is included. I'm guessing this is because ***would*** already implies something hypothetical / unreal / counterfactual - so it's a kind of "secondary negation", cancelling out the negation of "not expected". Consider these default interpretations / implications...

> 5) *I never expected him to hurt her* (implies he *did* hurt her, contrary to my expectations)
>     6) *I have never expected him to hurt her* (he *hasn't and won't* hurt her, as I expected)
>     7) *I would never expect him to hurt her* (implies he *hasn't and won't* hurt her)
>     8) *I would never have expected him to hurt her* (implies he *did* hurt her)

Comment: thank you very much indeed! You've really helped me to understand it all. Many, many thanks! :)